# Canvas HTML5 not ablbe to drag and drop an image in Ecllipse?

Tags: android, html, drag-and-drop, html5-canvas, android-canvas

I am new to HTML5. I am not able to drag and drop inside eclipse. This function is working in browser.

Please some one help me. Thanks in Advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#div1 {
    width: 350px;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
</style>
<script>
    function allowDrop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }
    function drag(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text", ev.target.id);
    }
    function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Drag the image into the rectangle:</p>
    <div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
    <br>
    <img id="drag1" src="ic_launcher.png" draggable="true"
        ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what does this have to do with Eclipse?  What does this have to do with Canvas?

Comment: This is just a drag and drop in Html. It is working in browse.But not working While attaching with Ecllipse with proper..Using the below ling i am doing this http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_getting-started_android_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Android